# Is there a more performant way of creating this array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

for one of my views I want to include a search field with jqueries typeahead function.

The array should contain all the attribute values of a client.

The array for the query is generated the following way:

```
@clients = []
Client.each do |client|
  @clients << client.attributes.values.join(' ')
end
```

Is this approach performant enough for a dataset of about 3000 entries? 
Or is there a better and faster solution?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers,
Patrick

## Update

One user mentioned to implement it like this:

```
@clients = Client.map do |client|
  client.attributes.values.join(' ')
end
```

This is another way to do it. But a benchmark reveals that this is no improvement in performance.

This leaves me with the question: Maybe there is a more performant way, but speaking about a maxium of 3000 records - does it really matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if ActiveRecord models would implement the `map` method (which they don't i believe), the two solutions suggested by the OP and @xdazz are time- and memory-complexity-wise equivalent. This can be observed with this simple benchmark:

```
require 'fruity'

# Dummy client class
class Client < Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name, :position, :company)
  class << self
    include Enumerable

    def each(&block)
      5000.times do
        yield Client.new('Firstname', 'Lastname', 'CEO', 'Company Inc.')
      end
    end
  end

  alias_method :attributes, :to_h
end


compare do
  schnika do
    clients = []
    Client.each do |client|
      clients << client.attributes.values.join(' ')
    end
    nil
  end

  xdazz do
    clients = Client.map do |client|
      client.attributes.values.join(' ')
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

Which will output

```
schnika is similar to xdazz
```

Also, when you look at the implementation of `map` (synonymous to `collect`), it becomes clear that really nothing else happens than in the OP's method:

```
static VALUE
rb_ary_collect(VALUE ary)
{
    long i;
    VALUE collect;

    RETURN_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0);
    collect = rb_ary_new2(RARRAY_LEN(ary));
    for (i = 0; i < RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
    rb_ary_push(collect, rb_yield(RARRAY_PTR(ary)[i]));
    }
    return collect;
}
```

This translates to:

```
class Array
  def collect
    collect = []
    self.each do |el|
      collect << yield(el)
    end
    collect
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your performance comparison between the two solutions.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `.map`:

```
@clients = Client.map do |client|
  client.attributes.values.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong but aren't you (and the OP) sending all the data you have in Clients (all 3000 entries), that seems insecure. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am sending the whole data to the view. But I just started with programming so I think my approaches are insecure/bad/ ... :) But I am thankful for any advices I get

Comment: I tried to give this a performance test against an activerecord model with around 3,000 rows, but map seems not to be a valid method of an activerecord class. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @RobHeaton Yes that worked. Doesn't seem to be any faster. Padde suggests that's not unexpected, so does anyone have any rationale for upvoting this as a faster or more efficient method?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to retrieve all the attributes (for example 'updated_at'), so the following may be faster:

```
@clients = Client.select([:name, :email, :id]).map do |client|
  client.attributes.values.join(' ')
end
```

Added the `id` in case you need to link to the client.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I dont need every attribute. Thanks for your idea as well. This gives a far more useful query string.